# Kids TV show combining live action and animation, kids fighting monsters after entering a photo booth

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, animated-series

Okay so I used to watch this TV show probably sometime between 2005 and 2012, I'm not really sure when though. The show combined live action and animation and I believe it aired on CW4Kids on weekends.

When the main characters were at school and with their families, the show was live action, but then they would have to go and fight these monster things (or maybe it was large insects?), so they would pass through a mall photo booth and the show would become completely animated, they were in maybe a game world or a sewer system or a computer circuit board or a maze? Not really sure what it was but it was dark and not outside.

The kids themselves had their own monster things which they would ride and fight from. The character's outfits matched the colour of their monster, the girl I believe was purple and green, one boy was blue and another was either orange or red. The group definitely had one girl and two boys and I think maybe another boy?

I also seem to remember that what they were fighting had something to do with technology.

During the time the show aired it must have been sort of popular because the characters and their monsters were McDonald's Happy Meal Toys.

Answer (score 1):

While there's no photo booth, could you be thinking of *[ReBoot: The Guardian Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReBoot:_The_Guardian_Code)*?

> Four teenaged gamers, who are members of an online game's highest-scoring team, meet in person on their first day at Alan Turing High School. Their enrollment was arranged by Vera, an artificial intelligence who has recruited the team as "Guardians" to physically enter and protect cyberspace.[5] Early in the series, Vera is given a human body and locked out of cyberspace, so she enrolls as an exchange student. The Guardians battle the Sourcerer, a human hacker who, unbeknownst to them, is the father of team-member Austin infected with "dark code" or malicious software. Dark code is the Sourcerer's primary weapon against the world's computer systems. After his initial run-in with the Guardians, the Sourcerer reactivates the computer virus named Megabyte, the main antagonist of the original *ReBoot*, to help him from inside cyberspace.

It's a mix of live-action and cartoon. They fight "cyber locusts". The theme is technology-based.

### Trailer

Comment: Oh wait... that one is more recent than I thought. Announced in 2013, released in 2018. But I'll keep it up for being a partial answer that might help someone in the future.